# How to describe that a function must accept a certain contructor and return an instance of it too?

Tags: haskell

I have data type:

```
data MyData = D1 {several_records} | D2 {several_records} | D3 {several_records} |
```

How can I create a function such that it accepts `MyData` and returns `MyData`, **but** an argument that it accepts and the return type must belong to the same constructor of `MyData`?

```
myFunc :: MyData -> MyData -- not presicely what I want
```

**And note that in my real project I have way more constructors of `MyData`, therefore simply enumerating them one by one for `MyFunc` isn't what I'm looking for -- I want to  generalize them all at once.**

Comment: Obviously, you can define the function as `f :: MyData -> MyData; f (D1 _ _ ) = D1 _ _; f (D2 _ _ _ ) D2 _ _ _`. etc., so are you asking how you can enforce this at the type-level so attempts to violate this condition won't type-check?  Or are you asking how you can write a function that handles hundreds of such constructors in some systematic way without having to write them out explicitly?

Comment: There is no type-level distinction between a value created by `D1` and a value created by `D2`. If you want to reflect the constraint that `myFunc (D1 ...)` can *only* return a value created by `D1` in the type of `myFunc`, you need to define your type differently.

Comment: Are the records the same in all constructors?

Answer (score 3):

With a GADT, perhaps:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

data MyDataTag = DT1 | DT2 | DT3
data MyData :: MyDataTag -> * where
 D1 :: { foo_record :: Int, bar_record :: String } -> MyData 'DT1
 D2 :: { baz_record :: Char } -> MyData 'DT2
 D3 :: { qux_record :: Double } -> MyData 'DT3

myFunc :: MyData a -> MyData a
myFunc (D1 foo bar) = D1 (foo + 1) (bar ++ "hello")
myFunc (D2 _) = D2 'x'
myFunc (D3 qux) = D3 (-qux)
```

Comment: Don't the constructor types have to use `'DT1`, etc?

Comment: no. Re-read my question carefully

Comment: @chepner You don't always need the `'` (I think it's only when there'd be ambiguity, and there's not here), though you do get a warning (`-Wunticked-promoted-constructors`). I'll add it anyway.

Comment: @Jarru Can you elaborate on what's wrong with this?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ah, right. `DT1` would have to be the type constructor, since the kind checker can infer that from the kind of `MyData`.

Comment: `Can you elaborate on what's wrong with this? ` --> `And note that in my real I have way more constructors of MyData, therefore simply enumerating them one by one for MyFunc isn't what I'm looking for -- I want to generalize them all at once.`

Comment: @Jarru In that case, I think this would be a lot easier to solve if you posted your actual `MyData` and `myFunc` as they stand now (in particular so we can see what `myFunc` actually does), rather than just a dummy placeholder.